# libc-bin errors when trying to install php

Tags: 12.04, php

i am trying to update and install php into my ubuntu server 12.04 using the command below:

```
apt-get upgrade php
apt-get install php5-curl php5-gd php5-mysql php5-pgsql
```

However i receive this error all the time:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.33.36); however:
  Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpq5 (9.1.10-0ubuntu12.04) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                   Setting up php5-curl (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) ...
Setting up php5-pgsql (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-33-generic
 linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic
 linux-image-server
 linux-server
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure whats wrong and why it cant process the linux-image files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related to PHP at all:

You are out of space on some disk (/boot perhaps?):

> gzip: stdout: No space left on device